# Positioning divs with CSS - Flex

Tags: css

I recently had a challenge for **Positioning divs with CSS**

**Challenge**:
You are allowed to use only one position property and use flex for the rest.

I am curious how it can be done with just flex. I was able to solve it with grid. But I have no clue how can I position it with flex without rearranging the HTML.

```html
<div id="root">
    <div id="a">
        <div>I should be on bottom right</div>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <div>I should be on top right</div>
        <div>I should be on top left</div>
        <div>I should be on bottom left</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Firstly, setting the main container's display to flex and then setting the `flex-direction` to `row-reverse` yields this as the result with the row order reversed

[image]

Set the `justify-content` to `space-between` pushes the row elements to their extremes and `align-items` to `flex-end` so that the elements are aligned to the bottom line of the container

[image]

Finally, set the **I should be on top right** `div`'s position to absolute and move it to extreme right, by setting it's `right` property to a finite value, in this case `8px`

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#b>div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="a">
    <div>I should be on bottom right</div>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <div>I should be on top right</div>
    <div>I should be on top left</div>
    <div>I should be on bottom left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```